# General way of passing arguments to functions in c

Tags: c, function, parameters

I would like to ask a certain question in regards to C programming.

I have a function which takes a parameter 'x'.

The function is supposed to do actions based up on the x.

So i have a source file where i have this function

```
file.c

   y=random number

And i want to call this function to do actions.

function(x);
```

> And now x must be equal to y
>
> Well the problem here is i want to pass y value to x.

Is there any regular way of doing so?

If there is any please help me understand and also to make it clearer.

Regards
Rookie

Comment: So just call function with y as an argument? `function(y)`..

Comment: It will take y value as the argument.Or will it recognize y as a new parameter.Forgive me i'm new to programming and learning bit by bit

Comment: There must be a limit for number of arguments. 255? Maybe you should use struct that envelops x and y in an instance.

Comment: yes.just one argument

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I did not understand your point.

Comment: You need to passly everything as a single parameter? Or you need something different?

Comment: I want to have that y value passed in to this function and x will equal to y value .That's it.:).I hope i made it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Within your function(x), x will be equal to whatever value is pass to the function. If you use function(y), then within the function, x will be equal to y. If you use function(7), then x would be equal to 7.
Functions are usually defined with a return type and a parameter type.

`void function( int x)`

would define function that takes a type of integer and returns nothing.

`int function( int x)`

would define a function that takes a integer value and returns a integer value.

`double function( int x, double z)`

would define a function that takes an integer and a floating point and returns a floating point value.

Comment: Yes, as in the above answer, "x" is just a place-holder in the function declaration...it can take on ANY value (as long as it's valid for the data type of the function argument), whether it's a variable or a constant.